# How to generate unique serial number with alert message after each form submission on django?

Tags: python, jquery, angularjs, django

on views.py i have used

```
from django.contrib import messages
 def personal_detail(request):
    messages.success(request, 'Form submitted successfully.')
   (some lines of code here)
    apply_online.save()

    return render(request,'users/applyonline.html')
```

and on templates

```
 <div>
    {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages%}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
              {{ message }}
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </div> 
    <div class="row">

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

      </div>
```

its working fine but I actually want to generate unique serial number like SK(date)(year)(serial_number) of this format ,can you please help me with this?

Comment: What's the rest of  your view look like?

Comment: i've edited the question kindly look through it.I don't think so other part of the view is connected with the solution that I am finding

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482972/unique-invoice-numbers-in-django-views-for-models/36485350#36485350). It may get you pointed in the right direction.